# Assert Success Message

Tags: fluent-assertions

is there a possibility to not "only" show messages in case a assertion fails but also in case an assertion was successful?

```
42.Should().Be(42); // could show something like this: 42 is 42 (OK)
```

I have already looked through the code but I have only found parts operating on the failure messages.